# How do I parse this string in ruby?

Tags: ruby, string

Could someone tell me how to parse this string

> From: Dela(deal@gmail.com) 
>   To: Roger(perter@gmail.com) 
>   Date: Monday,
>   Oct 11 Subject: about emma

and store it into a hash like:

```
{:from=> "Dela(deal@gmail.com)", :to=>"Roger(perter@gmail.com)", :date=>"Monday, Oct 11", :subject=>"about emma"}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> str = "From: Dela(deal@gmail.com) To: Roger(perter@gmail.com) Date: Monday, Oct 11 Subject: about emma"
>
> Hash[str.scan(/([a-zA-Z]+):\s+(.*?)(?=\z|[a-zA-Z]+:)/).map{|k, v| [k.downcase.to_sym, v]}]